# Aliexpress API - full ordering process

Tags: aliexpress

Does Aliexpress have an API that allows to make full ordering process? This means to have own eshop and just communicate with API (including payment via Aliexpress).

Comment: We provide automated ordering through AliExpress. Check out https://www.aliseeks.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They seem to have this [DEV Centre](https://web.archive.org/web/20180317210006/http://isvus.aliexpress.com/isv/index.htm) but they say that you have to be a seller to get registered not sure why. As a buyer I was looking to find a way to download my orders as they don't provide reports at all.

One problem with this is that its in Chinese so you may probably has to use browser with translation options like chrome.

Comment: Anyone wants to comment on "why they only allow seller account to access the api(s)."

Comment: I am not able to access the above link http://isvus.aliexpress.com/isv/index.htm Can anyone tell me is it changed or removed?