# how to buy item with aliexpress api

Tags: api, e-commerce

i am researching the aliexpress api and other 3rd party options.

i can't seem to find any option for buying anything automatically.
I have searched theit API as well as googled for other vendors or options. They mostly only have catalog downloads, price updaters and the likes.

does anyone know of a way to actually buy/order/purchase a product from aliexpress via an api?

thanks

Comment: any ideas anybody?

Comment: Same here. I'm looking through the docs, and I can't find any information about the process. Also, this seems to be a duplicate question for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36015618/aliexpress-api-full-ordering-process

Comment: so that makes 2 of us :-), if you can find an answer please post it here. thanks!

Comment: Now we are 3 :)

Comment: Now its been 4 too :)

Comment: Now we are 5 :(

Comment: Maybe you should try the Dropshipping API: https://developers.aliexpress.com/en/doc.htm?docId=39662&docType=2

Comment: Hello from 2022. Anyone has some good news on the subject?